# Find a polynomial P(X)

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Find a polynomial $P(x)$ such that it satisfies

$$2P(2x^2-1)=(P(x))^2-1$$

How to find all of them?

Answer (score 3):

As your goal is just to find *one* polynomial, I suggest to use $P(x) \equiv \lambda$ for a $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$. Then just solve $2 \lambda = \lambda^2 - 1$. (Fortunately, this has real solutions.)

[These are the only solutions.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1220982/119385)

Comment: That's cheeky! +1

Comment: There is these constant polynomials and no one else!

Comment: @Elaqqad: Well, there are *two* constant polynomials, which solve the equation. ;)

Comment: @Elaqqad: But why are there no non-constant solutions?

Comment: It's another question!

Comment: @Elaqqad: Okay, feel free to answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1220955). :)

Comment: @Elaqqad: Thanks, I saw that, I have already upvoted it. Normally I wait some time to give other users the chance for an even better answer, but that may not be necessary here. I accepted the answer. :)