# Non trivial solutions of a polynomial equation

Tags: polynomials

In [a question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1220936/find-a-polynomial-px/1220941) a user asked for a polynomial which solves

$$2P(2x^2-1)=(P(x))^2-1.$$

There are two solutions [I could provide](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1220941/119385), namely the two constant ones. However in the comments to my answer it has been mentioned there are no non-constant solutions. Question: Why?

Comment: Assume $P(x)=a+b x$ and develop $2P(2x^2-1)-(P(x))^2+1$ which will need to be equal to $0$. This will give you conditions for $a$and $b$. Each power of $x$ will need to have a coefficient equal to $0$.

Comment: Duplicate of [Find a polynomial P(X)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1220936/find-a-polynomial-px) People will (eventually) give a complete answer to that one.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici That shows it for a linear polynomial. How about the general case?

Comment: I know. I am working the general case. Cheers :-)

Comment: @MlazhinkaShungGronzalezLeWy: This is only a duplicate *after* you edited the other question.

Comment: No harm either way. It is a collaborative website. As long as at least one of them solves the problem.

Comment: @ArpanBanerjee. I give up !

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I gave up quite a long time ago!

Comment: where I have to post my solution here or there?

Comment: @MlazhinkaShungGronzalezLeWy: Oh, don‘t get me wrong. I was not upset by your effort, but rather confused whether it has been the best decision.

Comment: This is getting complicated. I think it's best to leave that other question as it was (not asking for _all_ solutions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $P(1)=a$ so we have $2a=a^2-1$. Now we want to prove that $P$ is constant and to do so we suppose that $P$ is not constant, then there exist an integer $n$ representing the multiplicity of $1$ in $P-a$, such that $$P(x)=(x-1)^nQ(x)+a\\ Q(1)\neq 0$$ and $n\geq 1$ (because $1$ is a root of $P(x)-a$), injecting it in the equation we obtain:$$(x-1)^nQ(x)^2+2aQ(x)=2(2x+2)^nQ(2x^2-1)$$ and for $x=1$ we obtain $2aQ(1)=2.2^nQ(1)$ impossible because $a\neq 2^n$ and $Q(1)\neq 0$.

**Conclusion** : All solutions to your equation are the constants solutions $a$ where $2a=a^2-1$